# How do you use 'if' to stop an empty Matrix block from displaying?

Tags: matrix

On a complex page, where there are different sections that need to be present in the template, but may not all have content added via Craft entries I need to stop the empty areas from being output (e.g. a set of div's that will create an ugly empty space in the page).

I can successfully do this for empty simple entries - like this:

```
{% if entry.modelTitleType %}
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <h2>{{ entry.modelTitleType }}</h2>
        <p>{{ entry.modelIntroType }}</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

So the div enclosed by the 'if' statement is only output if there's an entry added for 'modelTitleType'.  But I cannot get this to work for a Matrix entry!

How do I wrap an 'if' statement around a Matrix block like this, so it is only output if there's data added?

```
<ul class="selector padded-top inline-list">
    {% for block in entry.modelDataType1 %}
        {% if block.type == "type" %}
            <li><a class="button-list selected" id="show-type1" title="{{ block.typeName }}">{{ block.typeName }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for block in entry.modelDataType2 %}
        {% if block.type == "type" %}
            <li><a class="button-list" id="show-type2" title="{{ block.typeName }}">{{ block.typeName }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I've tried:

```
{% if entry.modelDataType1 %}
```

But this doesn't work...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Matrix field / block is empty it won't output at all but you can try checking the length in an if statement like:

```
{% if entry.modelDataType1 | length %}
    // matrix content here
{% endif %}
```